# Installing a drainable waterline to garage, draining into sump for winter months

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, hardware, pex

So, My utility room shares a common wall with my unheated garage. I've been toying around with the idea of running some pex out there to have a spigot in my garage. I'm wondering if I need to attach a drainage valve* to let the line drain off during the winter (Except when in use). The easiest way to handle this water would be to put a drain valve in the line, with the drainage line leading to the sump pit that is almost directly below the manifold.

Based on the fact that both the sump and water heater are sitting at a slightly lower level than the rest of the floor, so the heater will drain off into the sump if it starts leaking, I'm going to guess the sump is equipped to handle a sudden influx of water, probably more than would be in the approximately 5 ft of pex leading to the garage.

*I'm thinking of using a valve like this, if it exists, while I'm assuming it does. If such a valve exists, I'd love to know it's name

```
Open
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Water Flow -- >                          --- To Garage --->
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          |  To  |
                          | Sump |
                          |      |

Closed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Water Flow (blocked)- >|      <-- Line to garage drains back into sump -
---------------------------      ------------------------------------------
                          |  ||  |
                          |  ||  |
                          |  VV  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a valve with a built in drain like [this.](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Everflow-405P034-NL-3-4-PEX-Full-Port-Ball-Valve-w-Drain-Lead-Free)

Or put in two valves. One to shut off the main supply ahead of the sump and one to drain into the sump.

Good luck!